How does 1D Schrödinger equation arise out of the postulated 3D Schrödinger equation and solving 1D particle using 3D Schrödinger equation?
I've stumbled upon this question when I was trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for a particle confined to a 1D line with some given time independent potential $V(x)$.
The energy eigenstates could be simply obtained by solving $$\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V(x))\psi(x),$$ but I randomly thought of converting this to a 3D problem by taking,$$
V(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
    V(x)& \text{if }y = 0,z=0 \\
   \infty & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
We know that the solution to the above SE is $$\begin{cases}\psi(x,y,z)=\psi(x)&\text{if }y=0,z=0 \\ 0& otherwise.\end{cases}$$
Then I tried substituting this into the original 3D SE and see if it solves it,$$\frac{\partial^2\psi(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2\psi(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2\psi(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V(x,y,z))\psi(x,y,z),$$
But since $\psi$  has step discontinuities (non-zero on $x$ axis and zero everywhere else) it's partial derivatives with respect to $y$ and $z$ have Dirac deltas and second partial derivatives possibly have derivatives of it,so lhs will have derivatives of Dirac deltas and rhs wouldn't. Where have I gone wrong and how does one resolve this problem? Also how does one arrive at the 1D Schrödinger equation, considering the 3D version of it as a postulate?

Your "conversion" is wrong: 1D equation/solution comes from the assumption of homogeneous directions applied to 3D equations. Using Cartesian coordinates, if $y$, $z$ are homogeneous solution and the solution is not a function of these coordinates,

$\phi(x,y,z) = \phi^{(1)}(x)$
the action of the Laplacian on such a function is
$$\nabla^2 \phi(x,y,z) = \left( \partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy} + \partial_{zz} \right) \phi(x,y,z) =  \left( \partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy} + \partial_{zz} \right) \phi^{(1)}(x) =  \partial_{xx}  \phi^{(1)}(x) $$


Aren't the situations $\phi(x,y,z)=\phi(x)$ everywhere and $\phi(x,y,z)=\phi(x)$ "only on one line in space " i.e the x axis and $\phi=0$ otherwise,both different? And I feel when we say "a particle confined to a line" we mean the second situation.So I think my question still stands.

Also when you say $\phi =\phi(x)$ everywhere then it means at some point (x,y,z) where y,z$\neq$0 ,the particle will have a probability of $|\psi(x)|^2$ and not zero as required by the problem.

The particle standing on a line is not compatible with the potential field you provided

you're correct..I've edited the potential in my question,I think it should be fine now,please look into it.
